# Orthonormal basis given by the integral of a vector field along a curve orthogonal to the tangent

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-analysis, curves, vector-bundles

A friend and I are trying to understand the construction on section 3.2 of [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1006734619701) paper by Bernatzki and Ye. Suppose $\gamma$ is a smooth simple closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then this paper claims there exist vector fields $v_i: \gamma \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $i = 1,2,3$, such that $v_i \perp \dot{\gamma}$ everywhere, and the three vectors $V_i = \int_{\gamma} v_i(s) ds$, $s$ being the arc-length parameter, form an orthonormal basis. Furthermore, we can make the support of the $v_i$ arbitrarily small. Why is this true?

We know that each $v_i$ can be written as a linear combination $f_iN + g_i B$, with $(T,N,B)$ being the Frenet frame, $f_i$ and $g_i$ being functions, but the integrals $\int f_iN + g_i B$ don't seem to have particularly nice forms, even after applying the Frenet-Serret equations and integration by parts. I think almost any choice of $v_i$ should yield $V_i$ forming a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but there seems to be difficulty in proving this rigorously.

Comment: First, I cannot see the paper you've linked. Second, the notation for $V_i$ is horrible: It should be $\int_\gamma v_i\,ds$, should it not? Third, the title is totally misleading or else the text is wrong. Do you mean three vectors obtained by the integration, or do you mean a frame, varying as you move along the curve?

Comment: I fixed the link on the paper, I apologize for the confusion. I also fixed the title. To be clear, I am seeking the existence of three vector fields along the curve, each orthogonal to its tangent, such that their integrals form an orthonormal basis. However, I don't see the issue with the integral notation. You could also write $V_i = \int_{\gamma} v_i ds$ if you like.

Comment: You can write $\int_\gamma \vec F\cdot d\vec r$ (for a work line integral) or $\int_\gamma \vec F\,ds$ for a vector-valued integral, but I have no idea what $\int_\gamma \vec F\,d\vec r$ should mean. I will think about your question. I still cannot access the article, since I am retired and no longer have university privileges.

Comment: I couldn’t find this paper on the arXiv but here’s another link https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251120106_Minimal_Surfaces_with_an_Elastic_Boundary

Comment: I see the issue you’re raising. I’ll fix it.

Comment: This question is very similar to a lemma used by Nash in his $C^1$ embedding theorem. See Lemma 2.4.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.02551.pdf

Comment: @Funktorality Fascinating. I think my proof sketch below is quite similar, but very special to curves; some of the "final details" I omitted are the Gram-Schmidt sort of thing Nash worried about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unusual result, and I'm surprised the authors dismissed it as if it were standard and well-known. Here's the main idea. You can sort out the final details. Having the supports be very small is *required* and is the main trick, from my point of view. (Think delta functions, or smooth approximations thereto.)

For a closed space curve, it is well-known that the tangent indicatrix is "balanced" with respect to every direction. Indeed, assuming $\gamma$ is arclength parametrized (with length $L$), we have $\int_0^L T(s)\,ds = \int_0^L \gamma'(s)\,ds = 0$, and so $\int_0^L (T\cdot A)\,ds = 0$ for any vector $A$. The same principle applies to the vector field $\kappa N$ (but not to $N$ itself), since $T'=\kappa N$. In particular, if you fix $s_1$ and take $A=N(s_1)$, then since $(\kappa N)(s_1)\cdot A>0$ and the integral is $0$, by the intermediate value theorem there must be $s_2$ so that $(\kappa N)(s_2) \cdot A = 0$.

Let $\rho_1$ be a bump function with integral $1$ supported in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $s_1$, and let $\rho_2$ similarly be supported in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $s_2$. Let $v_1 = \rho_1 N$ and let $v_2 = \rho_2 N$. You can rescale to make $V_1$ and $V_2$ unit vectors; they won't quite be orthogonal, but I believe you can alter $v_2$ by adding a small multiple of $B$ to fix it.

Now, can we find $s_3$ so that $\alpha N(s_3)+\beta B(s_3)$ is orthogonal to both $N(s_1)$ and $N(s_2)$ for some scalars $\alpha,\beta$? If not, the normal plane to $\gamma$ at every $s$ never contains the vector $A=N(s_1)\times N(s_2)$. But this means that $T(s)\cdot A$ is always nonzero, contradicting our original observation that the tangent indicatrix is always balanced. So there is such an $s_3$, and once again we use our bump function trick to create $v_3$ and correct as necessary.

If you find some fatal flaws with this, let me know. And certainly let us know if you figure out a trivial solution, but I certainly didn't see one.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure Ted Shifrin's answer is correct, and here are the missing details on orthogonality.

From his answer, we can see that we can find $s_1,s_2,$ and $s_3$ such that some linear combination of $N(s_i)$ and $B(s_i)$ forms an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The tricky part is that after taking an approximation to the identity supported around small neighborhoods of the $s_i$ and integrating, we might no longer have that the integrated vectors are orthogonal.

Let us first assume that we found $s_1,s_2$ such that $N(s_1)$ and $N(s_2)$ are orthogonal. Assume $\rho_1$ a smooth function of compact support around $s_1$, and we can modify $\rho_1$'s support to be arbitrarily small and such that the mollified vector $V_1 = \int_0^L \rho_1(s)N(s)ds$ is arbitrarily close to $N(s_1)$. Now take another smooth approximation to the identity $\rho_2$ with compact support on an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $s_2$. We claim that we can adjust $v_2$ by writing $v_2 = \rho_2(s)N(s) + f(s)N(s) + g(s)B(s)$, where $f$ and $g$ are smooth with support is contained within that of $\rho_2$, such that $V_2 = \int_0^L \left[ \rho_2(s)N(s) + f(s)N(s) + g(s)B(s) \right]ds$ is orthogonal to $V_1$.

Before defining $f$, observe

\begin{align*}
\langle V_1, V_2 \rangle &= \langle V_1, \int_0^L \left[ \rho_2(s)N(s) + f(s)N(s) + g(s)B(s) \right]ds \rangle\\
&= \int_0^L \langle V_1, \rho_2(s)N(s)  \rangle + \langle V_1, f(s)N(s) + g(s)B(s) \rangle ds.
\end{align*}

So if we can find a smoothly varying solution $(f(s),g(s))$ to the equation $$-\langle V_1, \rho_2(s)N(s)  \rangle  = \langle V_1, f(s)N(s) + g(s)B(s) \rangle,$$ we will have proved orthogonality. However, we want to avoid the situation where the only solution we can choose is $f = -\rho_2, g = 0$, since this would force $v_2$ and hence $V_2$ to be zero.

To prove we can avoid this scenario, we need to prove an elementary lemma of linear algebra.

**Lemma**: If $(f,g) = (-\rho,0)$ is the only solution to $\langle V, (f+\rho)N + gB \rangle = 0$, then $V$ is a multiple of $N$.

**Proof**: We prove the contrapositive. Write $V = aT + bN + cB$ and suppose $V$ is not a multiple of $N$, so either $a \neq 0$ or $c \neq 0$. Our equation is equivalent to $b(f+\rho) + cg = 0$. If $c = 0$ (and thus $a \neq 0$), then $f = -\rho, g = 1$ is a solution. If $c \neq 0$, then $f = 0, g = \frac{-b\rho}{c}$ is a solution. $\square$

(The lemma is actually vacuously true; it will never be the case that $(-\rho,0)$ is the only solution, but now I don't need to prove that). Now we can assume that $\rho_1$ is chosen so that $V_1$ is close enough to $N(s_1)$ such that it is not a scalar multiple of any $N(s)$ for $s$ in the support of $\rho_2$.

For $s$ outside the support of $\rho_2$, we can take $f(s) = g(s) = 0$, which will mean the supports of $f$ and $g$ will lie inside that of $\rho_2$. If $\rho_2(s) > 0$, then $V_1$ is not a scalar multiple of $N(s)$, so by the lemma we can choose $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ to be something other than the trivial solution $f(s) = -\rho_2(s), g(s) = 0$.

To see these solutions are smoothly varying in $s$, we can observe that the choice of $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ corresponds to picking a point in the translated subspace $V_1^\perp \cap \text{span}(N(s),B(s)) -\rho_2(s)N(s)$ which avoids $-\rho_2(s)N$ on a set of positive $s$-measure. For fixed $s$, $V_1^\perp \cap \text{span}(N(s),B(s)) -\rho_2(s)N(s)$ is an affine subspace of dimension at least $1$ which smoothly varies. (Imagine a line in the $(N,B)$ plane which smoothly moves around, translated by $-\rho_2(s)$ in the $N$ direction). The only issue which could occur is when this line becomes the entire $(N,B)$ plane, corresponding to the situation when $V_1$ is parallel to $T$. If we are avoiding the point $-\rho_2(s)N$, then the line could become a plane for an isolated $s_0$, and then discontinuously jump to another line. If this occurs, we would be forced to select $(f(s_0),g(s_0)) = (-\rho_2(s_0),0)$ for this singular $s$ in order to maintain continuity of $f$ and $g$, but as this only occurs at an isolated $s_0$, we could still maintain that $(f(s),g(s)) \neq (-\rho_2(s),0)$ for $s$ in a punctured neighborhood of this $s_0$. And of course, should $V_1$ be parallel to $T(s)$ for a set of positive $s$-measure, meaning the intersection becomes a plane for more than an instant, then we could still choose points such that we avoid having $(f,g) = (-\rho_2,0)$, ensuring our selection is on the appropriate line once $T(s)$ ceases to be parallel to $V_1$.

For $V_3$, we have that a linear combination $U = \alpha N(s_3) + \beta B(s_3)$ is orthogonal to $N(s_1)$ and $N(s_2)$. Assume $U$ is of unit length, and take smooth functions $\alpha(s), \beta(s)$ such that $U(s) = \alpha(s)N(s) + \beta(s)B(s)$ is a unit frame and that $U(s_3) = U$. Likewise, set $W = -\beta N + \alpha B$ so that $U(s) \perp W(s)$ for all $s$. Now consider $\rho_3(s)U(s)$ with $\rho_3$ being a smooth approximation of the identity with arbitrarily small support around $s_3$. Again, we need to choose correction terms $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ with $v_3(s) = \rho_3(s)U(s) + f(s)U(s) + g(s)W(s)$ so $V_3 \perp V_1,V_2$. The difficulty here is that since we need to satisfy two simultaneous orthogonality equations, we have that our selection of points $f(s),g(s)$ must be on the mutual intersection of the planes $V_1^\perp - \rho_3(s)U(s)$, $V_2^\perp - \rho_3(s)U(s)$, and $\text{span}(N,B) = \text{span}(U,W)$, which is in general the single point $-\rho_3(s)U(s)$, and we could be forced into the situation that $V_3 = 0$, so we cannot hope to define $f$ and $g$ so that $v_3$ is pointwise orthogonal to both $V_1$ and $V_2$.

However, there already exists a unique (up to sign) unit $V_3$ orthogonal to $V_1$ and $V_2$. Choose the option that is closer to $U(s_3)$, and note that the distance to $U(s_3)$ can be made arbitrarily small by decreasing the supports of the $\rho_i$. Then we need to find another $(f,g)$ with support around a small $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $s_3$ satisfying $V_3 = \int_{s_3 - \varepsilon}^{s_3 + \varepsilon} \left[ \rho_3(s)U(s) + f(s)U(s) + g(s)W(s) \right]ds$.

Furthermore, assume the supports of $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are small enough such that $V_3$ is close enough to $U(s_3)$ to ensure the quantity $\langle V_3, U(s) \rangle$ is positive and bounded away from zero for $s \in (s_3-\varepsilon, s_3+\varepsilon)$.

To measure the deviance of $\int v_3 ds$ from $V_3$, we can take its inner product with $V_3$ and see how close it is to $1$. Observe

\begin{align*}
\langle V_3, \int_0^L v_3(s)ds \rangle &= \int_{s_3-\varepsilon}^{s_3+\varepsilon} \langle V_3, (\rho_3(s) + f(s))U(s) + g(s)W(s) \rangle ds.
\end{align*}
We need to solve the equation $\langle V_3, (\rho_3(s) + f(s))U(s) + g(s)W(s) \rangle = \rho_3(s)$, as this would ensure the integrand is $\rho_3(s)$, and thus have total integral $1$, proving $\langle V_3, \int v_3 \rangle = 1$.

Notice that for all $s$, $V_3 = \langle V_3,T(s)\rangle T(s) + \langle V_3, U(s) \rangle U(s) + \langle V_3, W(s) \rangle W(s)$. Thus, our equation becomes $\langle V_3, U(s) \rangle(\rho_3(s) + f(s)) + \langle V_3, W(s) \rangle g(s) = \rho_3(s)$. As $\langle V_3, U(s) \rangle \neq 0$, we have that $f(s) = \frac{\rho_3(s)}{\langle V_3, U(s) \rangle} - \frac{\langle V_3, W(s) \rangle}{ \langle V_3, U(s) \rangle}g(s) - \rho_3(s)$. Picking $g(s)$ to be any smooth function with compact support on $(s_3-\varepsilon,s_3+\varepsilon)$, we have smoothly defined $f(s)$. We can also see that $f(s) \to 0$ as $s \to s_3 \pm \varepsilon$, so $f$ also has compact support. After picking an appropriate $g$ to ensure $|\int v_3| = 1$, we are done.

Comment: I haven’t checked all the details, but I’m glad you worked this out. I’d be curious to ask the authors for a reference!